# backup aws ec2 data to a totally separate aws account

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to backup my AWS snapshots to a completely separate AWS account for additional security (if my AWS credentials were acquired someone could delete all my snapshots and volumes). But I'm a bit stumped on how to do this.

There doesn't seem to be a way to store a volume or snapshot in S3 such that another user could access that data in s3 and store it in a separate AWS account.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an IAM user and an S3 bucket from your secret (backup)
   account.
2. Add an [IAM policy](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingIAMPolicies.html) to the newly created bucket,
   allowing your newly created IAM user to put objects, but denying him
   to delete them.
3. Use IAM user account to upload your backups to S3.

Answer (score 0):

You can share any EBS snapshot with another account by adding this permission. Once the snapshot is shared, the other account can either copy that snapshot to their account or create a volume using that snapshot.